# Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'product'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I am going to pass list objects in url I am getting this error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `ProductForParameterSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'product'.
```

`

```
class ProductParameter(models.Model):
    product_attribute = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_parameters')
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='-')
```

and **serializers.py** looks like this

```
class ProductForParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='product.name', max_length=255, read_only=True)
    product_desc = serializers.CharField(source='product.description', max_length=255, read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='product.image', read_only=True)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(source='product.price', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, read_only=True)
    rating = serializers.CharField(source='product.rating', max_length=10, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductParameter
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'name', 'price', 'product_desc', 'image', 'rating')
```

as you can see in the model there is **Product** `ForeignKey`. In this model there may be more than one product and from this table I should get product which its id is unique. I do not need duplicate products. and for this I am using this view

```
class ProductForParameterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductForParameterSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        products = query_params.get('product', None)

        productParams = []

        if products is not None:
            for product in products.split('|'):
                productParams.append(int(product))

        if products is not None:
            queryset = ProductParameter.objects.all()
            queryset = queryset.filter(product_id__in=productParams)
            qs = queryset.values_list('product', flat=True).distinct()
            return qs
```

but I am getting error. How can I fix this? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Why do you want the API to return product when you also want it to return some Product fields? You could just write one ProductSerializer.

Comment: @Vincent yes you are right but if I write `ProductSerializer` it throws error either my problem is not that. When I give product id it return duplicate products. It should return only unique product. Can you help plz?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `queryset.values_list('product', flat=True).distinct()` in queryset which which give you a list of product ids. That is why you are getting this error. You should return list of products in your `get_queryset` method.

```
class ProductForParameterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductForParameterSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        products = query_params.get('product', None)

        productParams = []

        if products is not None:
            for product in products.split('|'):
                productParams.append(int(product))

        if products is not None:
            queryset = ProductParameter.objects.all()
            queryset = queryset.filter(product_id__in=productParams)
            qs = queryset.values_list('product', flat=True).distinct()
            return Product.objects.filter(id__in=qs)
```